# Google App Engine : user login page

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, openid

If I want to require users to be logged in to view any page on my web site, how do I achieve this? Do I check for user login status at the beginning of doGet() in every servlet class and redirect to the log-in page? Once the user logs in, then redirect back to the original servlet? Could I achieve the same thing with a simple configuration some where if such a thing exists?

Comment: To get an answer on SO you have to show that you put some effort into researching your problem. What did you try so far? Did you read the manual (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/?csw=1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag to your `web.xml` file:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This is will require the user to be authenticated in whatever role (`role-name`) to access any servlet (`url-pattern`)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this configuration out. It seemed to trigger redirecting to /_ah/login_required. I can't find anywhere on google documentation explaining what possible values can be used for <role-name>. I only see "*" and "admin" for it in the examples.

Comment: Sorry, I just found out the only values allowed in there are "*" or "admin". I wonder where you would define the admins.

Comment: The account with which you have created the app is the `admin`.

Comment: Thanks, h4k1m. I tried out your solution and it worked except I think the logged-in session is cached in the Google App Engine and I don't seem to have control over it. For example, (1) log into my google account in gmail and with the same browser when the site is opened, I am authenticated. (2) log out from my gmail and view the site again and I am still authenticated.

Comment: maybe you have to use `UserService` class to manage user session. It can be used to generate `loginUrl` & `logoutUrl` inside your app.